# serving static files using express for react

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a application , where i am serving the static files with the below code

// index.js - server folder

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'build')));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  })
```

;

i am able to get the html file but i am not able to get the js files inside the build  folder.

first it was not able to find the chunk.js files

so i have added "homepage": "." in my package.json for the client

then i was able to avoid the 404 file not found, but when i check the response of the chunk.js files its giving html code instead of the minified js code.

my base url of the application is https://www.example.com/app

see the below details

```
sampleapp
   client
     // using cra (create react app) files
     src
     public
     ...
   server
     index.js
   Dockerfile
```

// package.json -> inside client folder

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": ".",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4000"
}
```

// Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.15.1-alpine

COPY . /var/app

WORKDIR /var/app/client
RUN npm install --no-cache && npm run build && npm install -g serve


WORKDIR /var/app/server
RUN npm install --no-cache

EXPOSE 4000 

CMD [ "node","index.js" ]
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: but you catch all routes and send for it `index.html` remove `*` from route

Comment: okay let me check it

Comment: It this don't work open `console` in browser and check errors anc content downloaded from server

Comment: @bato3 one doubt for client side routing only i have added the /* , can you check this one from the official docs https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

Comment: @bato3 i didnt get your second comment ??

Comment: when i removed  "/*" its not able to get any of the files. if i add that one i am able to ge the files html file i am getting but the chunk.js files response is same as the html. I have a doubt in the "/*" like once we get the html file it is again checking for .js file in the src tag of html so in "/*" we are mentioning to load the html file for the js also. How we resolve this one

Comment: There is no support for `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` with .htaccess. You need `fs.existsSync` + `path.relative()`  or move librates to other dir `app.use('/static', express.static('public'));`

Comment: can you just post the answer, i didn't get your conclusion

Comment: app.use('/static', express.static('public')) , i dont have a public folder ??

Comment: If you use `.get('/*')` you must have most specific route for static files

Comment: can you update the index.js of the question and post as a answer, so i can try it

Comment: i got the solution thanks for the response @bato3